# ACCESS SQL: multiple tables and form input issues

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created two list boxes with dates in an Access form to allow the user to select a date range. The user can pick a date in the first list and a later date in the second list.

The form is called **Supplier History**, the first list (the "from" date list) is called **List3** and the second list (the "to" date list) is called **List5**.  [Edit: List0 in code below contains suppliernames]

The dates in these lists are obtained by merging two tables. The tables involve supplier data, one table called Item Master focuses on general information on the supplier, the second table called ZMCE has transaction data.

The goal is to calculate the average price that the supplier charges, over the selected date range. The price column InfoRecPrice is in table Item Master.

For example let's say the lists have the following dates
[image]

These come from table Item Master: this table has dates (in column **DateStamp**) 8/24/2015, 9/1/2015, 10/1/2015, 11/1/2015, 12/9/2015, 1/4/2016, 2/1/2016, 3/1/2016, 4/1/2016, 5/1/2016, 6/1/2016. Table ZMCE has all the other dates, in column **PODate**.

Let's say the user picks the highlighted dates. I want the code to calculate the average price (price is in item master) over that time period even though the exact highlighted dates are not in that specific table.

The code below gives me a blank output, no matter what dates I select (even if I select those that are exactly the dates in the item master table):

```
SELECT Avg([Item Master].InfoRecPrice) AS Expr1
FROM [Item Master]
WHERE ((([Item Master].DateStamp)>=[Forms]![Supplier History]![List3] And ([Item Master].DateStamp)<=[Forms]![Supplier History]![List5]) AND (([Item Master].SupplierName)=[Forms]![Supplier History]![List0]));
```

Comment: What is in List0 ?

Comment: Just a bunch of supplier names. All of them have dates in both tables.

Comment: On `List8`, change "Column Count" to 1 and "Fore Color" to "Text 1, Lighter 25%"

Comment: Check out Compact & Repair.  The database file you uploaded was 636,160 KB.  After compact, the file size was less than 700 KB.  I think you should also learn about Zip.

Comment: @HansUp I implemented the changes and it won't work (I'm implementing everything on original database).  Thanks for compacting suggestions - the real database is big. Over 200,000 rows per table, and many more columns.

Comment: Those are the changes I made in my copy of your database.  I selected YEC, 8/24/2015, and 12/9/2015.  Then in the Immediate window, `Debug.Print Forms![Supplier History]!List8.Value` showed me 4.7025

Comment: What SQL code did you use for list8? My old one above or your suggestion that you deleted?

Comment: I used your old one.

Comment: Does that number show up in the listbox in form view?

Comment: Yes, after I changed Column Count and Fore Color as I described earlier.  What does the same `Debug.Print` show you?

Comment: Gives me a null value.
I went into same test database, clicked Yec (then clicked refresh button), then from date (refresh), to date (refresh) and no number shows up. In that same form view I then go to the immediate view and enter the debugcode and get the value null. I implemented the changes you suggested.

Comment: Sent email to you. Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: It works now: For some reasoms List8 under "columns widths", my faulty dataset had 0;1 written in it. As soon as I removed that it worked. Thanks so much Hans! Greatly appreciated.